# How do you resume a Chrome Custom Tab on Android when opening your app through an Android App Link from another app?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, chrome-custom-tabs, android-app-links

Assume the following:

1. You open App1
2. App1 opens/starts a Chrome Custom Tab (as I understand it, this is a new activity that is pushed to the stack)
3. The Chrome Custom Tab opens App2 through an Android App Link
4. App2 opens App1 through an Android App Link

How do you then make App1 resume the Chrome Custom Tab activity? I assume you have to add the Android App Link intent-filter to the Chrome Custom Tab activity somehow in the AndroidManifest file, but I’m not sure if this is possible, and how you are supposed to do this.

Currently, when App2 opens App1, the Chrome Custom Tab disappears, as I am not sure how to specify that my Android App Link should resume the Chrome Custom Tab activity (resuming the most recent activity of App1 would also work, since the Chrome Custom Tab would always be the most recent activity, in my case).